# How to change color of png on hover?

Tags: html, css, icons, png

I made a "down arrow" in illustrator and saved it as a png with a transparent background. When I put it into my webpage as an img, it shows up in the original color, which is okay. 
I'm trying to do

```
  img:hover{color:red;}
```

and it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

### Update 2023

You may use CSS `hue-rotate` filter for changing image colors:

```
img:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

It is supported in most modern browsers — see [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=hue-rotate).

Besides, you could also save your image as an SVG (rather than a PNG) and style any part of the SVG as you need.

### Original answer (2015)

If you target modern browsers, you may use [CSS filters](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/).

The `hue-rotate` filter is suitable for changing colors:

```
filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
```

The exact amount of degrees depends on your image and expected results.

Note that CSS filters is a new feature, and its [browser support is limited](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

---

Alternatively, you may use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) technique, which works in all browsers of reasonable age.

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is set the image as a background-image using CSS. Then set a hover state using another version of the image (with a different colour). For example:

```
.element {
  background-image: url(your-image.png);
}

.element:hover {
  background-image: url(your-image-hover-version.png);
}
```

Depending where you're putting the image/class, you'll need to assign appropriate height/width (or using padding).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the image with an identical image of another color with an event (like hover).

html:

```
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="/images/Turtle.jpg" />
</div>
```

css:

```
   #cf {
      position:relative;
      height:281px;
      width:450px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }

    #cf img {
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #cf img.top:hover {
      opacity:0;
    }
```

In detail here:
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Answer (score 1):

I was also wondering about an easy way to do it like:

```
.img:hover {
      background: red;
}
```

or

```
.img:hover {
      color: red;
}
```

but no easy cross-browser support solutions were found. However, I found that some of the browser solutions were using SVG images that have a `fill` attribute which can be easily set by CSS.

However, if you use font-awesome (basically, it's a font where instead of characters you have different icons), it's easy to control with simple CSS attribute `color`, like in the ***second*** example

So, if you want the easiest solution - find SVG images for your project that correspond to the ones you use. I found this process a little bit painful and decided to learn how to convert png and `.jpg` and `.png` to `.svg`. There is a command-line tool that helps you do so and it's called [**potrace**](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/). One thing I would recommend looking at if you decide to use this tool is to use simple editors to contrast **dark** for everything you want to have converted into `path` for the given `.svg` and white/light **(not transparent)** colors to the background and the areas you don't want to see in your `.svg` file.

Answer (score 0):

Applying:

```
{color:red}
```

to any element means changing text color.

Try changing:

```
img:hover {color:red}
```

to:

```
img:hover {background-image: url('<insert url to red arrow here>');}
```

and this works if you only have one image. If you have many images and you want only one to change on hover, then set an ID for the image you want to change and change img and img:hover to #x and #x:hover and replace x with the name you given for the ID.

Here's an example (assume other HTML is intact and properly formatted):

```
<style type="text/css">
#abc:hover {background-image: url('redarrow.png');}
</style>    
<img ID="abc" src="normalarrow.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand this is an old post, however I found applying the approach Richard took worked, however adding 0px to the height and width, and then adjusting the margin and padding worked.

```
.share-icon img {
  background-image: url(../../../images/share-blk.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.share-icon:hover img {
  background-image: url(../../../images/share-pur.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a red one in illustrator and then create a script in your DOM file

```
<script>

    const myPng = 'path/to/png';
    const redPng = 'path/to/redPng';
    
    // get the node (say foo) you want this change to take effect
    const foobar = document.querySelector('foo')
    
    // for on focus you have to keep state
    let isFocused = false;
    
    
    
    foobar.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
    foobar.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
    foobar.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
    foobar.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    
    // if you want to have focus event 
    function onFocus() {
        this.querySelector('img').src = redPng;
        isFocused = true;
    }
    
    function onBlur() {
        isFocused = false;
        onMouseOut.call(this);
    }
    
    // if you want to hover
    
    function onMouseOver() {
        if (!isFocused) {
            this.querySelector('img').src = redPng;
        }
    }
    
    function onMouseOut() {
        if (!isFocused) {
            this.querySelector('img').src = myPng;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

if you dont intend to focus the png then remove focus related functionality

```
<script>
foobar.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
foobar.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);

function onMouseOver() {
    this.querySelector('img').src = redPng;
}

function onMouseOut() {
    this.querySelector('img').src = myPng;
}
</script>
```

this assumes that you have 2 png files made in illustrator and an html file.