# Change Color of PNG Image on hover with css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change image color on hover.

I've tried with this css

```
.white:hover .img-white{
       color:white;
}
```

And html is

```
<div class="white">
    <img class="img-white" src="assets/images/icon-img/icon-3.png">
</div>
```

please tell me about my question how to change png image color on hover.

Comment: If in doubt, always have a quick google of what you're currently using, MDN is a good source, so "color css MDN" google will give you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color - which states: `sets the foreground color value of an element's text` - you can't use this to change the colour.  You either need a different image or an overlay.

Comment: "*change image colour to white"* - what does that even mean? An image usually contains many colours - do you want all of them to be white? ie become a white box?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change color of png on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707466/how-to-change-color-of-png-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to change color, but you can change opacity of the image:

```css
.img-white:hover{
       opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="white">
    <img class="img-white" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
</div>
```

Edit:

Here's a version that makes the image "white":

```css
.img-white:hover{
       opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="white">
    <img class="img-white" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
</div>
```

Comment: but i want to change png  image color.

Comment: @Farhan what does that even mean?  An image *usually* contains many colours - do you want *all* of them to be white?  ie become a white box?

Comment: When you say color, what exactly that mean? you want that to complete white?

Comment: If so, change the opacity in this answer to 0:  `opacity:0;` - while not "white" it will be the same as the background (which in this case is white) so just make your background white.

Comment: If not image then yeah you can do something on that, unfortunately since it is image, as @freedomn-m said above it contains many colors and you cannot specifically dim some colors, however there are some cheatcodes which can help you  to make in a bit light but again it comes to the field of `opacity`. Hope you got what I mean.

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah making `opacity:0;` will be complete white or invisible, @Farhan is that what you need? if so then change opacity 0.5 to 0.

Answer (score -5):

Use the transition to give a more effect.  In the image hover uses this. 
webkit-filter: grayscale (0%); transition: 1s;

And in the image: -webkit-filter: grayscale (100%)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - please note this is an English only site - questions *and* answers in English please.